# Images not appearing in "release version" of app

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to require some local images within my react-native app. In dev mode, when the server is running, the images load fine, but when I use the release version none of the images visually appear. The rest of the app; however, seems to work just fine.

I'm loading the images like this:

```
// components/Test.js
export default function Test() {
    return (
        <Image source={ require('../assets/icons/food/cupcake.png') } />      
    );
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Do I need to change a setting in xcode or something? Also, in dev mode, I've noticed that the images seem to get requested from the dev/hot loading server on each render as opposed to getting bundled in like the javascript code.

I'm using:
 - react-native version 0.34
 - I have xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, below is my answer

When you are generating bundle , Also put --assets-dest ./

"react-native bundle --platform ios --assets-dest ./ --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle"

It will  generate main.jsbundle and Assets folder . 
Go to your Xcode right click add files to project and add main.jsbundle file to project.
Also drag and drop Assets folder and select create by reference (note: do not select create group).

Also check in main.jsbundle. it is using assets(small a) folder but generating Assets(Caps A). I just changed the generated folder from Assets to assets and import it to xcode and it start working

Hope it solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Not too experienced with react native, but xcode usually requires "copy bundle resources" to be set in the build phases of your target settings.